# Undefined procedure error in prolog SWI

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

Running prolog **SWI** on windows 8 for the first time.

this is my program (.pl) file, very basic just with 3 facts: (I'm a complete prolog beginner)

```
hello.
a.
b.
```

When I load it (consult) in prolog-SWI, and work with the program, I get this error in my output:

```
12 ?- b.
true.

13 ?- a.
true.

14 ?- c.
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: c/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Now if that is a simple error because `c` was never stated in the program as a fact then that is fine, but after looking at the examples online and the ones I had found in class Prolog in these examples replies `yes` when a fact is in the program, and `no` when it is not. Mine replies `true` if it is, and gives me that long error if it is not.

See this link for [example](http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/facts.html)

Where is replies `no` for foggy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SWI has a slightly different top level shell much inspired by [Prolog IV](http://www.prolog-heritage.org/en/ph40.html)'s shell. The idea is that you get back as an answer again an executable query.  Therefore `true.` instead of `yes` and `false.` instead of `no`. This is particularly useful if you want to "paste back" an answer into the next query.

```
?- append(Xs,Ys,[1,4,7]).
   Xs = [], Ys = [1,4,7]
;  Xs = [1], Ys = [4,7]
;  Xs = [1,4], Ys = [7]
;  Xs = [1,4,7], Ys = []
;  false.
```

It is even more useful, when you are working with constraints like `library(clpfd)`:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
   true.
?- X #> 3, X#>=Y,abs(X) #< 100.
   X in 4..99, X#>=Y, Y in inf..99.
```

The other problem is common default behavior in many systems: If there is no clause and no other mentioning of a particular predicate, the system assumes that you mistyped the name and gives you an error accordingly.
If you really insist (don't!), you can switch behavior time traveling into the late 1970s with `set_prolog_flag(unknown, fail).` but better switch it back immediately with `set_prolog_flag(unknown, error)`.